# MS studio 17 Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, runtime-error, corrupt

Hi i keep getting a stack around the variable nhour was corrupted error, and I can not figure out why. I am trying to have a time entered and check it to make sure it is a good input. making the array bigger or smaller seems not to work. I have also added checks in and the output seems find until I get the error

```
void DEPARTURETIME(string& szdepartureTime)
{
bool berror;
char cdeparture[9];
int nhour[2],
    nminute[2],
    nhourValue,
    nminuteValue;
nhour[0] = 0;
do
    {
        berror = false;
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Enter departure time. (HH:DDAM/PM)" << endl;
        cin >> cdeparture;
        cin.ignore();
        berror = ERRORCHECK();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 && berror != true; i++)
            {
                nhour[i] = CONVTOINT(cdeparture[i]);
            }
//Beginning of testing hour for errors
        if (nhour[0] > 1 && berror != true)
            {
                cout << "Error, can not exceed 12 hours." << endl;
                system("pause");
                berror = true;
            }
        else if (nhour[0] == 1)
            {
                nhour[0] *= 10;
            }
        cout << nhour[0] << nhour[1] << endl;
        nhourValue = nhour[0] + nhour[1];
        cout << nhourValue << endl;
        if (nhourValue > 12 || nhourValue <= 0 && berror != true)
            {
                cout << "Error, can not exceed 12 hours and can not be 
zero." << endl;
                system("pause");
                berror = true;
            }
//End of testing hour for errors
//Beginning of testing for a colon
        if (cdeparture[2] != ':' && berror != true)
            {
                cout << "Error, you need a colon inbetween hours and minutes." << endl;
                system("pause");
                berror = true;
            }
//End of testing for a colon
        for (int i = 3; i < 5 && berror != true; i++)
            {
                nminute[i] = CONVTOINT(cdeparture[i]);
            }
//Beginning of testing for minute errors
        if (nminute[3] > 6 && berror != true)
            {
                cout << "Error, minutes can not exceed 60." << endl;
                system("pause");
                berror = true;
            }
        else if (nminute[3] > 0 || berror != true)
            {
                nminute[3] *= 10;
            }
        nminuteValue = nminute[3] + nminute[4];
        if (nminuteValue > 60 && berror != true)
            {
                cout << "Error, minutes can not exceed 60." << endl;
                system("pause");
                berror = true;
            }
//End of testing for minute errors
        cdeparture[5] = toupper(cdeparture[5]);
        cdeparture[6] = toupper(cdeparture[6]);
//Beginning of testing for AM and PM errors
        if (cdeparture[5] != 'A' && cdeparture[5] != 'P' || cdeparture[6] != 'M' && berror != true)
            {
                cout << "Error, must have AM or PM." << endl;
                system("pause");
                berror = true;
            }
    } while (berror != false);
//End of testing for AM and PM errors
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            szdepartureTime += cdeparture[i];
        }
return;
```

}

and this is the other function that is called

```
int CONVTOINT(char cchar)
{
    int value = cchar - '0';
    if (value < 0 || value > 9)
        {
            cout << "Error, Convertion failed" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `nminute` as an array with two elements, but when you use it you're accessing elements 3 and 4 (which requires the array to have 5 elements).  Since you're accessing past the ends of the array, you run into Undefined Behavior.  In this case, your compiler has inserted code to detect this problem and is telling you about it.

To fix it, change the subscripting on `nminute` when used in the code to only access elements 0 and 1.

Comment: Fixed thank you, sorry I did not see such a simple mistake